# Bootstrap Selectpicker - noneResultsText is not working with optgroup

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

I am using bootstrap selectpicker to make the custom select box. Problem is noneResultsText is not coming with optgroup, when i am removing optgroup noneResultsText is working fine. Not sure what would be the solution.

HTML:

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" >
    <optgroup label="Picnic">
       <option>Alabama</option>
       <option>Alaska </option>
       <option>Arizona </option>    
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
           noneResultsText: 'I found no results'
      });
```

Working example :http://jsfiddle.net/9abm0hhy/24/

Comment: While searching, if there is no results found, It should show the message. It work fine as i remove the optgroup. you can check this link http://jsfiddle.net/9abm0hhy/25/

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, i just updated selectpicker.js with updated version and noneResulttet started working.